# sfDoctrineGuard - how to ALWAYS join sfGuardProfile to sfGuardUser

Tags: join, symfony1, doctrine, sfguard

I want to make it so that **anytime** the db is queried for an `sfGuardUserProfile` it is autmoatically joined and hydrated with its related `sfGuardUser`.

If i was using Propel 1.2 i would normally override the `doSelectStmt` method of the `sfGuardUserProfilePeer` class to inspect the `Criteria` and modify it as necessary as well as modifying the `hydrate` method of the `sfGuardUserProfile` class. Im not sure how to go about doing this in Doctrine though.

Comment: To each his own. Ive been using sfGuard since its first stable and it works for me. I think there have been maybe two times that its not met my requirements and ive written something from scratch to replace it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use Event Listeners. Read more about them in the doctrine documentation: [Event Listeners](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/event-listeners)

In symfony 1.4 sfGuardUser can be modified. It's by default in lib/model/doctrine/sfDoctrineGuardPLugin/sfGuardUser.class.php. You can add following preDqlSelect() method to modify the query. Note that it's not tested.

```
class sfGuardUser extends PluginsfGuardUser
{
  public function preDqlSelect($event)
  {
    $params = $event->getParams();
    $query  = $event->getQuery();
    $alias  = $params['alias'] . '.Profile';
    if ((!$query->isSubquery() || ($query->isSubquery() && $query->contains(' ' .     $params['alias'] . ' '))) && !$query->contains($alias)) 
    {   
      $query->innerJoin($alias);
    }   
  }
}
```

To make it working you need to have DQL callbacks turned on. You can do it in your ProjectConfiguration class:

```
  class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
  {
    public function configureDoctrine(Doctrine_Manager $manager)
    {  
      $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_USE_DQL_CALLBACKS, true);
    }  
  }
```

Comment: That seems to be what i was looking for... And welcome to Stack Overflow :-)

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with Coronatus, I think what you're looking to do can be achieved with:

http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin

See "Customize the sfGuardUser model".

Basically, the profile needs to be called "sf_guard_user_profile" and the relation set up, and then you should be able to use:

```
$this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getProfile();
```

I think the right profile model name is needed for some config file purposes but I may be wrong.

Comment: Well you can customize the model name... And yes that will work out of the box to retrieve the profile however if not manually joined when you query it will issue a seperate query to get the profile object - im trying to make the join automatic (essentially turning off lazy load for the profile model and no others.